# android how to add text and value in spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

how to add text and value in spinner. And how to get value selected in spinner. (Same as select option in html. eg. `<select><option value="1">Volvo</option></select>`)

activity_main.xml

```
<Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinner"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"/>
```

ActivityMain.java

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

  List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
  categories.add("Spinner 1");
  categories.add("Spinner 2");
  categories.add("Spinner 3");

  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

  dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

  spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: You need a custom `ArrayAdapter` rather than just an `ArrayAdapter<String>` if you want more than just text.

Comment: @Enrico - No, that is not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.